# Автомаппер ошибка при вызове через Api

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, automapper

Добрый день, у меня наблюдается интересная проблема с Automapperom

В своих проектах я использую Automapper 4.1.1, с большим объёмом кода внутри

Решение состоит из четырёх проектов

- Core - службы и расширения
- DataLayer - репозиторий и **автомаппер**
- MVC - стандартный веб проект MVC
- WebApi - веб служба API (недавно добавленная)

Для работы с данными я использую

1. Entity FrameWork 6.1.1
2. AutoMapper 4.1.1

База данных локальная, строка подключения хранится в web.config (в обоих проектах)

у меня две модели, **User** - это обьект базы, и **UserModel** - это бизнес модель

В уровне DATA мой класс выглядит следующим образом

```
namespace DataLayer
{
 internal static class Mapping
{
    static Mapping()
    {
        RegisterMappings();
    }

    public static TDestination Map<TSource, TDestination>(TSource source, TDestination destination)
    {
        return Mapper.Map(source, destination);
    }

    private static void RegisterMappings()
    {
        try
        {
            Mapper.AllowNullDestinationValues = true;
            //Mapping instruction for User
            Mapper.CreateMap<User, UserModel>().IgnoreAllPropertiesWithAnInaccessibleSetter().ReverseMap();

            Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
        }
     }
}
```

на базовом уровне

```
 public AuthenticationResult Login(string login, string password)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(login))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(login));

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(password));

        using (var db = new Context())
        {
            try
            {
                //Here my UserDbEntity model, and it already connected from Context
                var dbUser = db.Users.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(u => u.Login == login && u.IsActive && !u.IsDeleted);
                //mapping model
                var model = Mapping.Map(dbUser, new UserModel());

                //Some result logic here

                return result;
            }
        }
    }
```

в API и MVC проектах настроенны ссылки на остальные проекты и когда я вызываю из MVC проекта

```
CoreLayer.Login(string login, string pass)
```

он возвращает мне верные данные, **но когда я вызываю эту же инструкцию через API**

```
Unmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.
        Add a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom resolver, or modify the source/destination type
        ==================================================================
        ServiceModel -&gt;Service (Source member list)
        Core.Models.ServiceModel -&gt; Data.DB.Service (Source member list)

        Unmapped properties:
        Specialization
        ServiceTechnic
        ServiceTools
        RefRescueWorkTypes
```

все объекты которые вызвали исключение являются комплексными (модель внутри модели) и при работе с MVC проекта проходят маппинг без проблем, а с API выдают исключение.

Comment: А конфигурация маппера везде одна и таже используется (internal static class Mapping)?

Comment: Да, т.к. autommaper используется версии 4.1.1, то метод статичный, и все конфигурации хранятся в нём